# Loop in a loop to search for matches for multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, loops, vlookup

I have two workbooks and three sheets. For simplicity call them `wb1Sheet1`, `wb1Sheet2` and `wb2Sheet1`. My code is:

1. Looking in a column of `wb1Sheet2` for any (non-zero) values to use as criteria (Crit).
2. For each criterion it searches the specific column of `wb1Sheet1`.
3. Matching rows are copied to another workbook: `wb2Sheet1`.

It worked OK when I wrote this code for one defined criterion.
However when I tried to modify it to be a loop in a loop (compare each criterion with each row) it does not function.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook                     
Dim wb2 As Workbook                     
Dim src As Worksheet                    
Dim Dst As Worksheet                    
Dim src2 As Worksheet
Dim Crit As Range


Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook                '
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test.xlsx")            
Set src = wb1.Sheets("wb1Sheet1")    
Set Dst = wb2.Sheets("wb2Sheet1")          
Set src2 = wb1.Sheets("wb1Sheet2")

Dim LastRow As Long, r As Range
Dim CopyRange As Range

LastRow = src.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
For Each Crit In src2.Range("G10:G")
    For Each r In src.Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
        If r.Value = Crit Then                               
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow
            Else
                    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next Crit
Next r
If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A1")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get? and where?

Comment: Just a small pointer, change your `LastRow = src. ...` line to this: `src.Cells(src.Cells.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row`.  Otherwise, the `rows.count` will be from whatever the active sheet is.  Better to specify which sheet you want to use `Rows.Count` from.

Comment: Have you considered using `Autofilter` to find rows that match the criteria and `SpecialCells` to copy only the visible cells after filtering?

Comment: Wouldn't this immediately give you an error because it's an invalid range?? `src2.Range("G10:G")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected the code and added the feature to ignore empty cells as criteria. Now it works fine. Thank you for you suggestions. Unfortunately, to limit the loop I have to use a constant, since when I edited the LastRow as BruceWayne said, it gives an error "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

```
Sub Copy_Data_by_Criteria()

Dim wb1 As Workbook                     
Dim wb2 As Workbook                     
Dim src As Worksheet                    
Dim Dst As Worksheet                    
Dim src2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook                
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test.xlsx")            
Set src = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")    
Set Dst = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")          
Set src2 = wb1.Sheets("Base 1")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim Crit As Range

' LastRow = src.Cells(src.Cells.Rows.Count, "P").End(x1Up).Row    

For Each Crit In src2.Range("G10:G" & 30)
    If Crit <> "" Then
        For Each r In src.Range("P6:P" & 100)
            If r.Value = Crit Then                                  
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow
                Else
                        Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow)
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next Crit
If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A1")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: in the lastrow line, remove the `.Cells` between `src` and `.Rows.Count` and it will work.